# Button in ContentView that zooms to current location on MapBox map?

Tags: swift, swiftui, coordinates, mapbox, locationmanager

So....in my coordinator--which conforms to the mapbox delegate protocol, I can just do:

```
mapView.setCenter(mapView.userLocation!.coordinate, zoomLevel: 13, animated: true)
```

and this function works fine in the coordinator or when it is called in the mapView class. The only problem is I don't know how to pass this mapView instance around (specifically back into ContentView where I want to have a button that does the same thing). I also have a LocationManager struct but I don't know how much use that would be here. Is the passing of the MapView instance the simplest way to accomplish what I'd like to do?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo of solution (based on MapKit, but it not important for idea). Tested with Xcode 12.

```
struct DemoActionToMapView: View {
    @State private var centerToUser: () -> () = {}
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Center", action: centerToUser)
            MapView { map in
                self.centerToUser = {
                    map.setCenter(map.userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var configure: (MKMapView) -> () = { _ in }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let map = MKMapView()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            configure(map)
        }
        return map
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: In ContentView, I have to declare my MapView as MapView(parameterList) and when I try to add that { } code block, I get an error saying MapView.Type is not convertible to (parameterListDataTypes). To be more clear, I tried declaring it as MapView(parameterList) { map in self.centerToUser = { //Center to see function here } }